# Use XML DTD as template to generate XML in C#

Tags: c#

Only XML DTD is provided. How do I create XML from a giving class?

For simple DTD, I can use regular expression to extract the fields and populate a XML. But is there a systematic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a xsd schema from your DTD using visual studio.  Open the DTD in visual studio and look for the 'create schema' function.  Then from there, you can use the xsd.exe command line utility to generate your class >> xsd YourSchema.xsd /c.  With your newly generated class, you can use a XmlSerializer to serialize the object into XML.

Comment: Thx. But sometimes they will provide DTD dynamically. I know this is not a good practice.